# Why big-Oh is not always a worst case analysis of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am trying to learn analysis of algorithms and I am stuck with relation between `asymptotic notation`(big O...) and `cases`(best, worst and average).

I learn that the `Big O` notation defines an upper bound of an algorithm, i.e. it defines function can not grow more than its upper bound.

At first it sound to me as it calculates the worst case.
I google about(why worst case is not big O?) and got ample of answers which were not so simple to understand for beginner.

I concluded it as follows:
`Big O` is not always used to represent worst case analysis of algorithm because, suppose a algorithm which takes O(n) execution steps for best, average and worst input then it's best, average and worst case can be expressed as O(n).

Please tell me if I am correct or I am missing something as I don't have anyone to validate my understanding.
Please suggest a better example to understand why `Big O` is not always `worst case`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Big-O?

First let us see what `Big O` formally means:

> In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms
>   according to how their running time or space requirements grow as the
>   input size grows.

This means that, Big O notation characterizes functions according to their growth rates: *different functions with the same growth rate may be represented using the same O notation*. Here, O means **order of the function**, and it only provides an *upper bound* on the growth rate of the function.

---

Now let us look at the rules of Big O:

- If f(x) is a sum of several terms, if there is one with largest
  growth rate, it can be kept, and all others omitted
- If f(x) is a product of several factors, any constants (terms in the
  product that do not depend on x) can be omitted.

Example:

f(x) = 6x^4 − 2x^3 + 5

Using the 1st rule we can write it as, f(x) = 6x^4

Using the 2nd rule it will give us, O(x^4)

---

### What is **Worst Case**?

> Worst case analysis gives the maximum number of basic operations that
>   have to be performed during execution of the algorithm. It assumes
>   that the input is in the worst possible state and maximum work has to
>   be done to put things right.

For example, for a sorting algorithm which aims to sort an array in ascending order, the worst case occurs when the input array is in descending order. In this case maximum number of basic operations (comparisons and assignments) have to be done to set the array in ascending order.

It depends on a lot of things like:

- CPU (time) usage
- memory usage
- disk usage
- network usage

---

### What's the difference?

Big-O is often used to make statements about functions that measure the worst case behavior of an algorithm, but big-O notation doesn’t imply anything of the sort.

The important point here is we're talking in terms of growth, not number of operations. However, with algorithms we do talk about the number of operations relative to the input size.

Big-O is used for making statements about functions. The functions can measure time or space or cache misses or rabbits on an island or anything or nothing. Big-O notation doesn’t care.

In fact, when used for algorithms, big-O is almost never about time. It is about primitive operations.

When someone says that the time complexity of MergeSort is O(nlogn), they usually mean that the number of comparisons that MergeSort makes is O(nlogn). That in itself doesn’t tell us what the time complexity of any particular MergeSort might be because that would depend how much time it takes to make a comparison. In other words, the O(nlogn) refers to comparisons as the primitive operation.

The important point here is that when big-O is applied to algorithms, there is always an underlying model of computation. The claim that the time complexity of MergeSort is O(nlogn), is implicitly referencing an model of computation where a comparison takes constant time and everything else is free.

Example -

If we are sorting strings that are kk bytes long, we might take “read a byte” as a primitive operation that takes constant time with everything else being free.

In this model, MergeSort makes O(nlogn) string comparisons each of which makes O(k) byte comparisons, so the time complexity is O(k⋅nlogn). One common implementation of RadixSort will make k passes over the n strings with each pass reading one byte, and so has time complexity O(nk).

Comment: If you're going to quote someone's blog post (http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/big-o.html), please credit them and clean up the errors caused by copy-pasting mathjax (for example: "make kk passes over the nn strings" should be "make k passes over the n strings"). My own opinion is that this answer copies just too much of the original author's work without making any significant changes or improvements.

Answer (score 3):

The two are not the same thing.  Worst-case analysis as other have said is identifying instances for which the algorithm takes the longest to complete (i.e., takes the most number of steps), then formulating a growth function using this.  One can analyze the worst-case time complexity using Big-Oh, or even other variants such as Big-Omega and Big-Theta (in fact, Big-Theta is usually what you want, though often Big-Oh is used for ease of comprehension by those not as much into theory).  One important detail and why worst-case analysis is useful is that the algorithm will run no slower than it does in the worst case.  Worst-case analysis is a method of analysis we use in analyzing algorithms.

Big-Oh itself is an asymptotic measure of a growth function; this can be totally independent as people can use Big-Oh to not even measure an algorithm's time complexity; its origins stem from Number Theory.  You are correct to say it is the asymptotic upper bound of a growth function; but the manner you prescribe and construct the growth function comes from your analysis.  The Big-Oh of a growth function itself means little to nothing without context as it only says something about the function you are analyzing.  Keep in mind there can be infinitely many algorithms that could be constructed that share the same time complexity (by the definition of Big-Oh, Big-Oh is a set of growth functions).

In short, worst-case analysis is how you build your growth function, Big-Oh notation is one method of analyzing said growth function.  Then, we can compare that result against other worst-case time complexities of competing algorithms for a given problem.  Worst-case analysis if done correctly yields the worst-case running time if done exactly (you can cut a lot of corners and still get the correct asymptotics if you use a barometer), and using this growth function yields the worst-case time complexity of the algorithm.  Big-Oh alone doesn't guarantee the worst-case time complexity as you had to make the growth function itself.  For instance, I could utilize Big-Oh notation for any other kind of analysis (e.g., best case, average case).  It really depends on what you're trying to capture.  For instance, Big-Omega is great for lower bounds.

Imagine a hypothetical algorithm that in best case only needs to do 1 step, in the worst case needs to do n2 steps, but in average (expected) case, only needs to do n steps. With n being the input size.
For each of these 3 cases you could calculate a function that describes the time complexity of this algorithm.
    1   Best case has O(1) because the function f(x)=1 is really the highest we can go, but also the lowest we can go in this case, omega(1). Since Omega is equal to O (the upper bound and lower bound), we state that this function, in the best case, behaves like theta(1).
    2   We could do the same analysis for the worst case and figure out that O(n2 ) = omega(n2 ) =theta(n2 ).
    3   Same counts for the average case but with theta( n ).
So in theory you could determine 3 cases of an algorithm and for those 3 cases calculate the lower/upper/thight bounds. I hope this clears things up a bit.

> https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3qtgsh/how_is_big_o_not_the_same_as_worst_case_or_big/

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation shows how an algorithm grows with respect to input size.  It says nothing of which algorithm is faster because it doesn't account for constant set up time (which can dominate if you have small input sizes).  So when you say

> which takes O(n) execution steps

this almost doesn't mean anything.  Big O doesn't say how many execution steps there are.  There are C + O(n) steps (where C is a constant) and this algorithm grows at rate n depending on input size.

Big O can be used for best, worst, or average cases.  Let's take sorting as an example.  Bubble sort is a naive O(n^2) sorting algorithm, but when the list is sorted it takes O(n).  Quicksort is often used for sorting (the GNU standard C library uses it with some modifications). It preforms at O(n log n), however this is only true if the pivot chosen splits the array in to two equal sized pieces (on average). In the worst case we get an empty array one side of the pivot and Quicksort performs at O(n^2).

As Big O shows how an algorithm grows with respect to size, you can look at any aspect of an algorithm. Its best case, average case, worst case in both time and/or memory usage.  And it tells you how these grow when the input size grows - but it doesn't say which is faster.

If you deal with small sizes then Big O won't matter - but an analysis can tell you how things will go when your input sizes increase.

Answer (score 1):

One example of where the worst case might not be the asymptotic limit: suppose you have an algorithm that works on the set difference between some set and the input.  It might run in *O*(*N*) time, but get faster as the input gets larger and knocks more values out of the working set.

Or, to get more abstract, *f*(*x*) = 1/*x* for *x* > 0 is a decreasing *O*(1) function.

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on time as a fairly common item of interest, but Big-O can also be used to evaluate resource requirements such as memory.  It's essential for you to realize that Big-O tells how the runtime or resource requirements of a problem *scale* (asymptotically) as the problem size increases.  It does *not* give you a prediction of the actual time required.  Predicting the actual runtimes would require us to know the constants and lower order terms in the prediction formula, which are dependent on the hardware, operating system, language, compiler, etc.  Using Big-O allows us to discuss algorithm behaviors while sidestepping all of those dependencies.

Let's talk about how to interpret Big-O scalability using a few examples.  If a problem is O(1), it takes the same amount of time regardless of the problem size.  That may be a nanosecond or a thousand seconds, but in the limit doubling or tripling the size of the problem does not change the time.  If a problem is O(n), then doubling or tripling the problem size will (asymptotically) double or triple the amounts of time required, respectively.  If a problem is O(n^2), then doubling or tripling the problem size will (asymptotically) take 4 or 9 times as long, respectively.  And so on...

Lots of algorithms have different performance for their best, average, or worst cases. Sorting provides some fairly straightforward examples of how best, average, and worst case analyses may differ.

I'll assume that you know how [*insertion sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) works.  In the worst case, the list could be reverse ordered, in which case each pass has to move the value currently being considered as far to the left as possible, for all items.  That yields O(n^2) behavior.  Doubling the list size will take four times as long.  More likely, the list of inputs is in randomized order.  In that case, on average each item has to move half the distance towards the front of the list.  That's less than in the worst case, but only by a constant.  It's still O(n^2), so sorting a randomized list that's twice as large as our first randomized list will quadruple the amount of time required, on average.  It will be faster than the worst case (due to the constants involved), but it scales in the same way.  The best case, however, is when the list is already sorted.  In that case, you check each item to see if it needs to be slid towards the front, and immediately find the answer is "no," so after checking each of the n values you're done in O(n) time.  Consequently, using insertion sort for an already ordered list that is twice the size only takes twice as long rather than four times as long.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, in that you can say certainly say that an algorithm runs in **O(f(n))** time in the best or average case.  We do that all the time for, say, quicksort, which is **O(N log N)** on average, but only **O(N^2)** worst case.

Unless otherwise specified, however, when you say that an algorithm runs in **O(f(n))** time, you are saying the algorithm runs in **O(f(n))** time *in the worst case*.  At least that's the way it should be.  Sometimes people get sloppy, and you will often hear that a hash table is **O(1)** when in the worst case it is actually worse.

The other way in which a big O definition can fail to characterize the worst case is that it's an *upper bound only*.  Any function in **O(N)** is *also* in **O(N^2)** and **O(2^N)**, so we would be entirely correct to say that quicksort takes **O(2^N)** time.  We just don't say that because it isn't useful to do so.

Big Theta and Big Omega are there to specify lower bounds and tight bounds respectively.

Comment: >>> `Unless otherwise specified` Actually it's mathematical definition of Big 0: lim sup |f(x)| as x --> ∞, up to a constant. So I would dare to call it "asymptotic worst case", in the OP's parlor.

Comment: "worst case" does not mean "worst possible value of x"

Answer (score -1):

There are two "**different**" and most important tools:

- the best, worst, and average-case complexity are for generating numerical function over the size of possible problem instances (e.g. f(x) = 2x^2 + 8x - 4) but it is very difficult to work precisely with these functions
- big O notation extract the main point; "how efficient the algorithm is", it ignore a lot of non important things like constants and ... and give you a big picture

Comment: "how efficient the algorithm is" - it doesn't do this at all.

Comment: Yes, it does. "The Algorithm Design Manual" by Steven S.Skiena page 34

Comment: Can you please provide the exact reference? https://mimoza.marmara.edu.tr/~msakalli/cse706_12/SkienaTheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf

Comment: sure, bottom of page 47 (take-home lesson) for example

Comment: You've taken it out of context. It says "compare the efficiency of algorithms" not "how efficient the algorithm is". That's two different things. Comparing allows me to tell if algorithm A is more efficient than B if they do the same task. It does not tell me how efficient either algorithm actually is.

Comment: I believe it gives us rough idea of "how efficient" an algorithm is, but your opinion is more accurate.