# Still not understanding Big-O vs Worst Case Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, linear-search

The worst case for time taken by linear search is when the item is at the end of the list/array, or doesn't exist. In this case, the algorithm will need to perform `n` comparisons, to see if each element is the required value, assuming `n` is the length of the array/list.

From what I've understood of big-O notation, it makes sense to say that the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n), as it COULD happen that the worst case occurs, and big-O is used when we want to make a conservative estimate of the "worst case".

From a lot posts and answers on Stack Overflow, it seems this thinking is flawed, with claims made such as *Big-O notation has nothing to do with the worst case analysis.*

Please help me to understand the distinction in a way that doesn't just add to my confusion, as the answers here: [Why big-Oh is not always a worst case analysis of an algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849158/why-big-oh-is-not-always-a-worst-case-analysis-of-an-algorithm) do.

I'm not seeing how big-O has NOTHING to do with worst case analysis. From my current hilltop, it looks like big-O expresses how the worst case grows as the input size grows, which seems very much "to do" with worst-case analysis.

Statements such as this, from https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/the-big-scary-o-notation-ce9352d827ce :

*As an example, worst case analysis gives the maximum number of operations assuming that the input is in the worst possible state, while the big o notation express the max number of operations done in the worst case.*

don't help much, as I cannot see what distinction is being referred to.

Any added clarity much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The big-O notation is indeed independent of the worst-case analysis. It applies to any function you want.

In the case of a linear seach,

- the worst-case complexity is O(n) (in fact even Θ(n)),
- the average-case complexity is O(n) (in fact even Θ(n)),
- the best-case complexity is O(1) (in fact even Θ(1)).

---

So big-O and worst-case are different concepts, though a big-O bound for the running time of an algorithm must hold for the worst-case.

Comment: *"though a big-O bound for the running time of an algorithm must hold for the worst-case."* - This is misleading. You could use big O to describe the best case of an algorithm, and then the same complexity class would not necessarily hold for the worst case.

Comment: @kaya3: I assume that you did not read my whole post.

Comment: I did read the whole of your post, and I think the part I quoted is misleading for the reason I stated.

Comment: @kaya3: when you read the whole post, it is not misleading.

Answer (score -1):

This is the case:

> If an algorithm to find a solution for a problem is in `O(f(n))`, means that the worst-case scenario for finding the solution for the problem by the algorithm is in `O(f(n))`.  In other words, if the worst-case scenario can be found in `g(n)` steps by the algorithm, then `g(n)` is in `O(f(n))`.

For example, for the search algorithm, as you have mentioned, we know that the worst-case scenario can be found in `O(n)`. Now, although the algorithm is in `O(n)`, we can say the algorithm is in `O(n^2)` as well. As you see, here is the distinction between *Big-Oh* complexity and the worst-case scenario.

In sum, the worst-case scenario complexity of an algorithm is a subset of the Big-Oh complexity of the algorithm.